# Need help in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this xml:

```
    <mappings>      
        <mapping>       
           <name iskey="true">234</name>     
           <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>    
           <bid iskey="true">sim</bid>    
           <data>GSSS</data>     
        </mapping>     
        <mapping>     
          <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>     
          <bid iskey="true">sim</bid>    
          <data>TS</data>    
        </mapping>    
        <mapping>    
          <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>
          <account>TS</account>     
        </mapping> 
     </mappings>
```

> I need the xpath to select the node which has node `<aid iskey='true'>bmz</aid>` and no other node containing iskey attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few back and forth in comments it seems like you are looking to get a hold of the `mapping` node (or any other node for that matter) that has the `aid` child node with a certain attributes and value but no other child nodes with the `@iskey` attribute. You do it like this:

```
//*[aid/@iskey='true' and aid/text()='bmz'][not(*[@iskey][local-name() != 'aid'])]
```

The predicate says exactly that: has the `aid` child node with those values and doesn't have a child node with a name other than `aid` that would happen to have an `@iskey` attribute.

When I run this simple test stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//*[aid/@iskey='true' and aid/text()='bmz'][not(*[@iskey][local-name() != 'aid'])]"/>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

on your input document I get the following in return:

```
<mapping>
    <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>   <!-- I need this node -->
    <account>TS</account>
</mapping>
```

**UPDATE** if you were looking to get a hold of nodes that only have one child node with the `@iskey`, you can get away with:

```
//*[count(*[@iskey]) = 1]
```

I plugged it into my test stylesheet and it produced the same expected result:

```
<mapping>
    <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>   <!-- I need this node -->
    <account>TS</account>
</mapping>
```

Comment: not working. First returns null and second returns the first node. I need the last node from the above xml having only two tags.

Comment: There are three nodes that are `<aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>`. if you need the last one then you can go about it like this: `//aid[@iskey='true' and text() = 'bmz'][last()]`

Comment: `//aid[@iskey='true' and text() = 'bmz'][last()]` will select all last nodes with specified attributes of their parents from this xml. `//mapping[last()]/aid` probably will ok

Comment: 'all last nodes' - I mean all three nodes from this xml will be selected :)

Comment: I need a genric xpath. It is not necessary to pick the last node. I want to select node containing aid = 'bmz' and iskey='true' and no other node has iskey attribute.The first and second node has bid and name nodes that contain iskey attributes. The last node satisfy the condition. SO i need the last node.

Comment: ok, now I see. those are not attributes, those are child nodes. so maybe you formulate your question better? you need to get a hold of the `mapping` node that only has that `aid` node as a child and no other `mapping` nodes?

Comment: no other nodes containing iskey attribute. The last mapping node has only one node having iskey attribute.

Comment: right. that's what my solution does now, I believe. if you are looking for nodes that have only one child with the @iskey attribute that would be a little different. which one is it?

Comment: I simply need this part `<mapping>`
`    <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>   <!-- I need this node -->`
`    <account>TS</account>`
`</mapping>`

Comment: that's what the solution does. either one. hope it helps. if it's what you were looking for please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Use this shorter and simpler XPath expression**:

```
   /*/*
     [aid[@iskey='true' and .='bmz']
    and
      not(*[not(self::aid)][@iskey])
      ]
```

**Explanation**:

This is a simple, specific case of the "**[Double Negation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)**"  :)

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/*
     [aid[@iskey='true' and .='bmz']
    and
      not(*[not(self::aid)][@iskey])
      ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<mappings>
    <mapping>
        <name iskey="true">234</name>
        <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>
        <bid iskey="true">sim</bid>
        <data>GSSS</data>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>
        <bid iskey="true">sim</bid>
        <data>TS</data>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>
        <account>TS</account>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected elements (just one in this case) are copied to the output**:

```
<mapping>
   <aid iskey="true">bmz</aid>
   <account>TS</account>
</mapping>
```

Comment: nice. The more I think about this particular one the more I believe we should actually go by equality of `generate-id()` rather then `local-name()` or `self::aid` to avoid duplicates. Either solution with node names in it will allow for two or more `<aid iskey="">` childnodes

Comment: @PavelVeller: The OP says "the node" because in his example there is only one such element. In general, if there are more than one such elements all of them are selected. In this case the OP can add additional constraints to get only the 1st such node or the one that also matches some additional requirement.

Comment: One last thing, from the above xml I need the second node( the middle one ) containg aid and bid tags and data tag. Then what will be the xpath ?   I trid this `/*/*[aid[@iskey='true and .='bmz'] and not(*[not(self::aid)[@iskey]) and bid[@iskey='true' and .='sim'] and not(*[not(self::aid)][@iskey]) ]` but I'm getting error "it contains  invalid token"

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: Just append `/aid` to the expression.

Comment: yahoooooo I write this predicate and got the results `//*[aid/@iskey='true' and aid/text()='bmz'][bid/@iskey='true' and bid/text()='sim'][not(*[@iskey][local-name() != 'aid' and local-name() != 'bid'])]`

Comment: Can I accept 2 answers ? bcz Pavel Veller answer is also correct and I already marked it as my answer.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: Only one of the answers can be accepted at any time. It is recommended to accept the answer that you feel is best.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev.Please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365104/using-translate-function-in-xpath-gives-error/11365277#11365277