# Using translate function in XPath gives error

Tags: xml, xpath

I have to do a case-insensitive XML search. I've written XPath expressions which are working fine, but when I use the `translate` function inside an XPath expression I get an error. Below are the XPath expressions that are working fine:

```
string upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

string xpath = "/data/item[AID/@iskey='true' and AID/text() = 'fep'][not(*[@iskey][local-name() != 'AID' ])]";       

string xpath1 = "/data/item[translate('Aid','" + upper + "','" + lower + "')]";
```

And here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<item>
 <AID iskey="true">fep</AID>
  <account>MS</account>
  </item>
</data>
```

I want to place the `translate` function in the first XPath expression like this:

```
 string xpath = "/data/item[translate('AID','" + upper + "','" + lower + "')/@iskey='true' and translate('AID','" + upper + "','" + lower + "')/text() = 'fep'][not(*[@iskey][local-name() != translate('aid','" + upper + "','" + lower + "') ])]";
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

> **Expression must evaluate to a node-set.**

This xpath is working fine for me.

```
 string col="AID"; 
 string xpath = "/data/item[col/@iskey='true' and col/text() = 'fep'][not(*[@iskey][local-name() != 'col' ])]";
```

Now my requirement is that the col value can be in any case upper case or lower case, so I want a change in my  xpath with which it returns me the result irrespective of in which case data is present in the xml.
 If a user gives aid or Aid or aiD it returns me the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that in your XPath expression you have a location step like this:

```
item['aid'/@isKey = 'true' ...]
```

The subexpression:

```
'aid'/@isKey
```

is syntactically illegal in XPath, because the left-hand-side of the `/` operator must be a node-set -- here it is just a string.

**You want to have an XPath expression like this -- not the one you are generating at present**:

```
/data/item
       [*[translate(name(), 'aid', 'AID') = 'AID']/@iskey='true'
      and
        *[translate(name(), 'aid', 'AID') = 'AID'] = 'fep'
         ]
          [not(*[@iskey]
                [translate(name(), 'aid', 'AID') != 'AID']
             )
         ]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'aid'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'AID'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "/data/item
           [*[translate(name(), 'aid', 'AID') = 'AID']/@iskey='true'
          and
            *[translate(name(), 'aid', 'AID') = 'AID'] = 'fep'
             ]
              [not(*[@iskey]
                    [translate(name(), 'aid', 'AID') != 'AID']
                 )
             ]
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<data>
    <item>
        <AID iskey="true">fep</AID>
        <account>MS</account>
    </item>
</data>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes (just one in this case) are copied to the output**:

```
<item>
   <AID iskey="true">fep</AID>
   <account>MS</account>
</item>
```

**Update**:

The OP has difficulty understanding this solution.  This is an example to show him that the solution works for any capitalisation of the string "aid":

When the transformation above is applied on an XML document, that contains element names that are any capitalization of "aid" -- such as this:

```
<data>
    <item>
        <aId iskey="true">fep</aId>
        <account>MS</account>
    </item>
</data>
```

**again the expected result is produced**:

```
<item>
   <aId iskey="true">fep</aId>
   <account>MS</account>
</item>
```

**Update 2**:

The OP still doesn't understand the solution and claims that for a specific XML document -- provided below -- "I used your expression it returns null "

**Here is the XML document as provided in the comment of the OP:**

```
<data>
    <item>
        <aId iskey="true">fep</aId>
        <account>FG</account>
    </item>
</data>
```

**When the same XSLT verification is run against this document, *again* the correct element is selected and output**:

```
<item>
   <aId iskey="true">fep</aId>
   <account>FG</account>
</item>
```

Comment: yes. Do you check this expression ? I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: See my updated answer -- this works correctly when used in XSLT.

Comment: yeah, it's working. but there is one problem you put translate function equal to 'AID' which is fixed ? . It can be aid or AiD or aID etc, so when I change it to 'aid' the expression returns null. It want it to be case insensitive.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: The code is correct and you need to understand it. In the XPath expression "AiD" is translated to "AID" and this is equal to "AID" so the result of the comparison is true. Exactly the same happens when handling "aID". I recommend that you also run the transformation with different inputs to see for yourself that it is working correctly in all cases.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: Your last comment shows definitely that you *don't* understand the code. As I said, *try* the transformation with *every possible source XML document* you can come up with to see that it works correctly in every case.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: See the update to the answer -- in it the same transformation is applied on another XML document where the name of the element is "aId" -- and, contrary to your concerns, the transformation works OK in this case -- in fact, if/when you understand the code, you will know that the transformation works as wanted for any capitalization of "aid". Try it with as many different capitalizations, as you want. :)

Comment: In Translate function you convert the node name or value and compare it with 'AID' ? am i right ? I made a little change with your expression and it returns null. The problem is here `string xpath = "/data/item[*[translate(name(),"+lower+" ,"+upper+") = 'aID']/@iskey='true' and *[translate(name(), "+lower+","+upper+") = 'aID']/text() = 'fep'][not(*[@iskey][translate(name(),"+lower+","+upper+") != 'aID'])]";` You Put translate function to be equal to 'AID', you saw it in the xml. When I changed it, the result is null

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: You want your XPath expression to work with any element whose name is one of all possible capitalization of the string 'aid'. This is exactly what the XPath expression in this answer is expressing. The modifications that you made to the XPath expression are incorrect -- it must not be modified -- and naturally you produced a wrong XPath expression that serves no purpose.

Comment: You have not understand my problem. I want a dynamic xpath. I have this xml now.`<data>
 <item>
  <aId iskey="true">fep</aId> 
  <account>FG</account> 
  </item>
</data>` when I used your expression it returns null and when I made a litle change it to `string xpath1 = "/data/item[*[translate(name()," + lower + " ," + upper + ") = 'aId']/@iskey='true' and *[translate(name(), " + lower + "," + upper + ") = 'aId'] = 'fep'][not(*[@iskey][translate(name()," + lower + "," + upper + ") != 'aId'])]";` it works, also read my question again, I will now write some more explanation

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: Actually, *the same* expression correctly selects the `item` element when evaluated on the document you say you have problems with. I will add a second update to the answer in a few minutes -- showing the XSLT - based verification.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: Second update added -- it shows that your claim is wrong -- the same XPath expression correctly selects the wanted `item` element from the XML document you provided in your last comment.

Comment: Thank You so much dear :) I just miss the single quotes around the upper and lower variables due to which I'm not able to get the correct answers.

Comment: can u please refer me some xml ebook ? or tutorial and also i never work on stylesheet, i don't know about, if you have good links for learning plz share it with me

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: Sure. Have a look at this answer -- it contains pointers to good resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `translate()`, try using a union: `(aid|AID)`

New xpath:

```
/data/item[(aid|AID)/@iskey='true' and (aid|AID)/text() = 'fep'][not(*[@iskey][local-name() != 'AID' and local-name() != 'aid'])]
```

Comment: it is not fixed, it can be Aid, aiD, AId,AiD etc. I want case insensitive xpath.